# How to get 2.7 from np.array(2.7)?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy it is easy to retrieve `2.7` from `np.array([2.7])`, but I get stuck when trying to retrieve the value `2.7` from an array like this: `np.array(2.7)`.

How can I retrieve the value `2.7` from it?

More concretely, I need a function

```
def get(a):
   ......
```

so that `get(np.array(2.7))=2.7`. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: a = numpy.array(2.7)

In [3]: a[()]
Out[3]: 2.7000000000000002
```

You might want to think about why you even have a 0-dimensional array, though. They're kind of weird, and it can be a bit finicky whether operations on a 0D array produce a scalar or an array.

(The extra `...02` you see is because 2.7 isn't exactly representable in floating point, indexing arrays gives you NumPy scalars instead of Python scalars, and NumPy's display logic is slightly different from Python's.)

Answer (score 0):

`np.array(2.7)` is a zero dimensional array. You cannot index into them:

```
>>> arr = np.array(2.7)
>>> arr[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

For most practical purposes, you can use these arrays just like you would use a regular float or integers.

```
>>> arr*2
5.4000000000000004
>>> arr+1
3.7000000000000002
>>> float(arr)
2.7
```

In response to your comment:

> What is the intuition that it is 0-dimension?

Well, one example where you could see it is accessing the array's `shape` attribute.

```
>>> arr.shape
()
>>> np.array([2.7]).shape
(1,)
```

Comment: Thanks. I see you point. But what is the intuition that np.array(2.7) is 0-dimension?

Comment: @zell: Count the layers of nested brackets. Don't see any? That's 0D.

Comment: While you can use 0-d arrays as normal numbers, you're still working with the precision that numpy has set for you. For example, `a = np.array(2); a ** 40`. However, `a.item()` will return a Python int and `a.item() ** 40` will give you a long result. (Tested on Python 2.7 with Numpy 1.8.1)